# Can I add a channel to a specific conda environment?

Tags: python, environment, conda

I want to add a conda channel to a specific [conda environment](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) but when I use

```
conda config --add channels glotzer
```

that channel is now available from all my conda environments.  In addition to testing an install from another environment, the `~/.condarc` file has the following:

```
channels:
  - glotzer
  - defaults
```

How would I configure conda so the channel is only available from a specific environment?

I did find in the [channel documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/channels.html) that for conda >= 4.1.0, putting channels at the bottom of the `~/.condarc` will prevent added channels from overiding the core package set.

> By default conda now prefers packages from a higher priority channel over any version from a lower priority channel. Therefore you can now safely put channels at the bottom of your
>   channel list to provide additional packages that are not in the
>   default channels, and still be confident that these channels will not
>   override the core package set.

I expect this will prevent most problems, except when in one environment you do want the package added through a channel to override a core package.

Comment: My experience has been that this is not possible (yet). What I do in these situations is remember to specify the channel to all install/update commands, for instance `conda update -c conda-forge --all` works well. Beware though that all the possible packages will be installed from `conda-forge` then.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As of conda 4.2, environment-specific `.condarc` files are supported and you can write:

```
conda config --env --add channels glotzer
```

to add the channel to the configuration for the active environment.

[*Not sure whether `--env` flag was added in 4.2. Answer based on conda 4.5.9*]

Comment: This sounds perfect.  Do you know if this has been added to the documentation?  Could you add a link?

Comment: Just type `conda config -h`

Comment: you can also `conda config --env --append channels glotzer` to add this as the last entry rather than the first.

Comment: After that, `conda config --env --set channel_priority strict` may come useful too.

Comment: Use `conda config --env --get` to get env specific configuration.

Comment: @ShahrokhBah Is this the way to enforce the specific active environment to only use the sources written in `.condarc`?

Comment: @Breno As stated for a similar circumstance on https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html, this will ensure that all the dependencies come from the `glotzer` channel unless they exist only on `defaults`.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell you can find the documentation [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/config.html#Config%20File%20Location%20Selection).

Answer (score 11):

### **Update**

As of Jan 2017, it was not possible to add a channel to a single conda environment.  As of Dec 2020, this is now possible as described in [Christopher Barber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51747791/3585557).

---

### Alternative

If you instead want to install a package from a specific channel but do not want to add that channel to the global `~/.condarc` file, you should use the option to install a package from a specific channel:

```
conda install <some-package> -c glotzer
```

Comment: This is no longer true. Per-environment .condarc files have been supported since conda 4.2.

Answer (score 10):

You can create an `environment.yml` file containing the specification of your `conda` environment. The full docs are [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), but the basic setup is as follows:

```
name: EnvironmentName
channels:
    - conda-forge
    - glotzer
dependencies:
    - pip:
        - tensorflow
    - pandas=0.22.*
```

To use the environment, type

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
conda activate EnvironmentName
```

To update the environment when `environment.yml` is changed or packages are updated,

```
conda env update -f environment.yml
conda activate EnvironmentName
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Furthermore the channels in the `environment.yml` file are only used to create the environment and do not get added to the default configuration of the environment (i.e. no `.condarc` file is created for the environment containing its channels), so installing additional packages will require manually specifying the channels on the command line.

Comment: I only ever create environments using an `environment.yml` file, and in a non-default environment, I never use `conda install` — I always update the environment file, then `conda --env update`. This way the environment file always represents the current state of the environment, which makes my environments 100% portable — the file contains all the info needed to recreate them.

Comment: Yeah it is good practice, but Steven wants to add a channel to an existing environment. At least the question implies that.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new environment with a specific channel:

`conda create -n EnvironmentName -c ChannelName`