# Why would one add a channel to a conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

One can add channels (e.g. conda-forge) to conda via

```sh
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

For completeness, since conda 4.2 one can add channels (e.g. conda-forge) to specific environments via

```sh
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
```

([see also this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51747791/7403431)).

I am wondering if there are any other considerations why one might want to add (or not) a channel to conda / a specific conda environment other than sheer convenience of installing packages without specifying `-c conda-forge`?

Are there any advantages / disadvantages in adding channels?

Comment: In my case, I want to have a dev/beta environment that points to a dev conda channel and a separate prod environment only pointing to the prod channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly convenience - i.e., the `conda install` command is sufficiently expressive to specify any channel prioritization. For example, one can specify [the recommended Bioconda channel priorities](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) manually at each install:

```
conda install -n metagenomics_env --override-channels -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults kraken
```

but setting it on a per-env basis let's one set and forget

```
conda activate metagenomics_env
conda config --env --add channels defaults
conda config --env --add channels bioconda
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
...
conda install -n metagenomics_env kraken
```

This can be quite helpful when one has a diversity of projects that aren't conducive to having a single, global channel prioritization.

One issue that one should be aware of is that running `conda env export` always results in exporting the global channel configuration. While build IDs are included in the `environment.yml`, and are usually sufficiently distinct to capture channel of origin, if the channel isn't in the global `channels` configuration, then the builds won't be found if the system recreating the env doesn't have that channel in their config.

---

### Additional Uses

It is also worth emphasizing that the `--env` flag enables every config option to be set on an env-specific basis, not just channels. This can be useful for some edge cases, such as [specifying a subdir constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58014896/570918) (e.g., **win-32** vs **win-64**) or enabling experimental features [like `pip_interop_enabled`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58889047/570918) only in specific envs.